# Is there an equivalent of ACX for people outside the US and the UK?

Tags: audiobook

I was intending to create an audiobook version of my book by recording my own narration, and then upload and distribute it via [Amazon's ACX service](http://www.acx.com/), which in turn makes the audiobook available on Amazon, iTunes, and Audible.

However, just today I noticed that unlike Amazon's Kindle and CreateSpace (POD) services, [ACX **publishing** is only available for people in the US and UK](http://www.acx.com/help/the-basics/200474410#international), and I am in neither. It is not enough to be able to provide an address in either place, there are tax forms that are required which make it more than a simple matter of using a friend's or relative's address.

I would like to make the audiobook version of my book available on Amazon, iTunes, and Audible, ideally by going through a single service. Does such a service exist for those of us not in the US or UK?

I have, of course, done some Google searching, but I am getting a bit lost between services that want to narrate the book for you by connecting you with professional narrators, and publishing services that want to approach the issue of considering representing your audiobook like a traditional publisher. I'm just looking for a way to upload and distribute.

Answer (score 1):

No. There's no equivalent. It is likely that Amazon has exclusive deals with the other dominant players you mention, preventing third parties from doing the same.